Generate PDF in Next 15, load Template based on variable
I want to generate a PDF in my Next.js 15 app with react-pdf. The Template for the PDF should be loaded according to the slug from the db, which is a variable.
something like:
import {MyDocument} from `@/components/documents/${slug}`

Any Ideas on how to archive that?
